# How to inspect BitGenerator state in a numpy.random.Generator object?

Tags: numpy, random, numpy-random

If I have a `numpy.random.Generator`, what's the best way to inspect the `BitGenerator` used internally? And does the `BitGenerator` have any state that impacts what numbers are generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a generator in my test work space

```
In [101]: rng.__getstate__()
Out[101]: 
{'bit_generator': 'PCG64',
 'state': {'state': 146432235854318609275567707501468323380,
  'inc': 280910788252749725750054959837409577313},
 'has_uint32': 0,
 'uinteger': 454544037}
```

After creating some random numbers the `state` changes

```
'state': {'state': 189704257871557326744081098317112680436,
```

Comment: i also added an answer but i'm accepting yours as a thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know it's lame to answer my own question but i did just figure out that `_bit_generator` is an attribute of `Generator` objects:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)

>>> print(rng._bit_generator)

<numpy.random._pcg64.PCG64 at 0x7f97c7bb7b90>

>>> print(rng._bit_generator.state)

{'bit_generator': 'PCG64',
 'state': {'state': 35399562948360463058890781895381311971,
  'inc': 87136372517582989555478159403783844777},
 'has_uint32': 0,
 'uinteger': 0}
```